# Average Rate of Change of a Function Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I more than likely do not understand the property of real numbers thoroughly; thus, please explain what I don't understand as if I am a 5 year old.

1) A function is given. Determine the average rate of change of the function between the given values of the variable.

f(x) = 1/x;     x= 1, x=a

f(a) - f(1) / a-1 = My answer is a-1 /a^2-a

The books answer is -1/a

I am simplifying incorrectly? Please show work or explain as if I am a 5 year old.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For 5 years old you are not doing badly. But there is an error. The correct result is $$\frac{f(a)-f(1)}{a-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{a}-1}{a-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{a}(1-a)}{a-1}%
=-\frac{1}{a}$$